# Powershell script check if datetime is SortableDateTimePattern

Tags: datetime, powershell

I want to be able to check that a datetime parameter is in the form of a SortableDateTimePattern.

I only want to allow this format, or alternatively the same format but without seconds, ie:

```
2007-08-30T11:20
```

Any ideas on this would be very helpful, I'm fairly new to scripting so I don't really know where to begin.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Is code really needed here? My question is simple enough to do without. As I've said, I don't really have any clue how to accomplish this, so I'm looking for some kind of starting point. I'm not sure you read my question.

Comment: I read your question, you have showed no research effort of your own.  Some code to show the community what you have tried or some words around different approaches you have considered will always generate a better response than posting what amounts to 'I need to do something, I don't know where to begin so I haven't tried or considered anything'.  Perhaps hover your cursor over the down-vote button above and read the pop-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test if it can be parsed using a sortable format specifier. The sortable format specifier is "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss" or just "s" for short:

```
try
{
    [datetime]::ParseExact('2007-08-30T11:20','s',$null)
}
catch
{
    Write-Error $_
}
```